# idiom - come to a rumbling halt

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

I would like ask you foe help with meaning for "come to rumbling halt".

Is the same meaning as "to come to a grinding halt"?

The context is that the pumps stopped working - and the full sentence is - Pumps came to a rumbling halt.

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you look up rumbling, or rumble? It’s just an adjective here.

Comment: Dear @Xanne, - rumbling is the core word. And because "come to halt" and "to come to a grinding halt" are idioms, i thought that this could be idiom too. With "rumbling" as plain adjectvie the meaning does not make sense to me.

Comment: @VilemRousi If is is an idiom, it is an inept one.  ‘screeching halt’ and ‘grinding halt’ are onomatopoeic, suggesting the sounds of an abrupt halt.  I have never heard a ‘rumbling’ halt’.  But may be the context of a car driving into a long stretch of deep gravel might justify it.  Otherwise it is inept.

Comment: A sound and motion of a car or truck or train coming to a halt can be described many ways, which are descriptive, possibly typical, but not idioms. Be creative.

Comment: It's not an idiom.

Comment: The context is that the pumps stopped working - and the full sentence is - Pumps came to a rumbling halt.

Comment: The pumps rumbled as they came to a halt.  What's the question???

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to%20a%20rumbling%20halt%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: Close as I can tell, the  idiom originates from the sound of a train coming to a halt.  Prior to the effective use of air brakes (which sometimes weren't/aren't used on small trains even though present), as a train stopped and the engine braked the cars would transition from pulling on the hitches to pressing on them.  As each hitch went through this transition it would bang, so the end result would be a rhythmic banging as the 20 or so cars in the train each banged in sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Come to rumbling halt' means to stop suddenly with a deep resonant sound. For sample reference, in 'The Alchemy of Murder' by Carol Mcleary uses the same words as : "The snoring comes to a rumbling halt and the man's eyes flutter open."

Reference: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=h22JpZMyNgcC&pg=PT128&lpg=PT128&dq=come+to+rumbling+halt&source=bl&ots=UMa6lrRHdr&sig=ACfU3U0TlE74HCj9YDF-l7-2cEeEy-eNbg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwir_JeX9bbkAhVu7nMBHcnRALUQ6AEwCXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=come%20to%20rumbling%20halt&f=false

It doesn't sound like an idiom. Thank you friend for the question.

Answer (score -1):

There is no idiom *come to a rumbling halt*.

The closest expressions (perhaps more slang than idioms) are:

[**Slow your roll**](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/slow-(one%27s)-roll)

> [The Online Slang Dictionary]
> slow (one's) roll
> verb
>
> - to slow down.
>
> > Slow your roll.
>
> to stop a certain behavior, such as drinking too much or too quickly, getting loud and obnoxious in a bar, or spending too much money.
>
> > Hey, slow your roll with those shots!
> > Slow your roll! It's my play! (In the game of dominoes, to indicate that someone is playing out of turn.)

[**Pump your brakes**](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/pump-(one%27s)-brakes)

> [The Online Slang Dictionary]
> pump (one's) brakes
>
> - term used to tell someone to slow down or calm down
>
> > You have no reason to be yelling - pump your breaks.

---

Those expressions aside, the phrase in the question is not an idiom. Nor, as it's used *in the question* is it metaphorical—it's actually literal.

Comment: "Regional economies had come to a rumbling halt"

Comment: "There they bring the sentence to a rumbling halt, like some locomotive meeting the terminal buffers" https://books.google.com/books?id=EiWvCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA162&dq=%22to+a+rumbling+halt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih-piwxbjkAhUGuZ4KHZP4CYAQ6AEwAHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22to%20a%20rumbling%20halt%22&f=false